How to get Orthometric (or geoid) Elevation in QField?
enter image description hereHow to get Orthometric (or geoid) Elevation in QField?
Is it possible to import Geoid model in QGIS? Or calculate by some function?
Because in QField I can only get Ellipsoidal elevation.
I need in QField to set elevation in orthometric height not ellipsiodal like in Trimble Mobile Manager.
Is it possible to convert geoid from .txt to .gtx format? So I could import it into QField.



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you tried this option that appears in the documentation? https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/gnss/#altitude-correction-vertical-grid-shift

On the documentation of Qfield (link), you will find this:

Altitude values can be corrected with vertical grid shift files to calculate orthometric height.
Vertical grid shift files have to be made available to QField by putting them into the QField app folder :/Android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/QField/proj.
Once the grid shift file is placed there, it is available in QField in the Positioning settings under Vertical grid shift in use.
If you are using altitude correction and an external positioning device is used, consider turning Use orthometric altitude from device off.


The formats currently supported are:
GeoTIFF (.tif, .tiff)
NOAA Vertical Datum (.gtx)
NTv2 Datum Grid Shift (.gsb)
Natural Resources Canada's Geoid (.byn)

And this table :

